# laravel and vue, loading view without expected prop

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-5.8

I asked a question about this earlier but I'm still stuck and having some issues.

Right now, if I go to site.com/status/12345 then I will get my status as I would expect. The route with the id (12345) hits a controller method which passes that id in and returns the json version of it in the view, where I'm using it as a prop and calling a function with it on page load.

However, if I just go to site.com/status (which should hit my index method, returning only the base view) then I get 'undefined variable entryKey'.

Obviously, I'm adding my entryKey value from the controller into my blade to be passed in as a prop, which seems to be working if there is a URL segment for it, but now I can't just get my base view to return with `site.com/status`

How can I fix this so that `site.com/status` hits my index method and `site.com/status/12345` hits the detail method and passes the id in as a prop?

web.php (routes)

```
Route::get('/entry/status', 'entry\entryController@index')
    ->name('entry.status');
Route::get('/entry/status/{id}', 'entry\entryController@details')
    ->name('entry.status');
```

controller.php

```
public function index() {

    return view('entry.status');
}

public function details($id) {

    if (request()->wantsJson()) {
        return json_encode(entry::getDetails($id));
    }

    $entryID = json_encode($id);
    return view('entry.status')
        ->with('entryKey', $entryID);
}
```

status.blade.php

```
 <entry-dashboard :entry-key="{{$entryKey}}"></entry-dashboard>
```

detail.vue

```
props: [
'entryKey'
],
created() {
  this.setDetailWindow(this.entryKey);
},
setDetailWindow(event) {

  this.detailId = event.taskt_id;

  axios.get('/entry/status/' + this.detailId)
    .then(response => {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Remove the colon before `:entry-key`, you're not using any Vue expression binding

Comment: @Phil ok I just removed it but I still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: This is all very confusing. What view is `entry.status`? Is that `status.blade.php`? If so, why does it include a component that attempts to load the `/entry/status/{id}` route which would just result in loading the same view? Why do both your server-side routes return the same view?

Comment: I'm using one view to show details of a targeted entry. So if they load the entry/status view, it shows all entries and if they click an entry, that will call the entry/status/{id} route in order to load the details for the clicked entry. I"m trying to make it so that if they put in the external URL of status/12345 then it would act as if they clicked it on the view itself. I'm loading everything within one page

Comment: I actually think I resolved it by creating a new blade for the external call and only having that blade use the prop, but load the same component